# How to forward declare a custom constructor?

Tags: c++

Note: I have found the issue with how my Xcode was compiling the below and it appears unrelated to the topic discussed herein. When I have more details I will provide them here.

I recommend voting to close my question as "too localized" since it was an Xcode problem, unrelated to the c++ code itself. Many thanks for the help all the same as I did learn from the answers.

The below question (now answered and resolved) was caused by a confusing exclusion of a file from the Xcode target, thus there were no compiler errors even though the file had problems.

---

I have a pure virtual interface and want to define its factory method, which returns a subclass of this interface. This works fine:

```
struct MyVirt{
...all virtual stuff
};

class SubVirt; //forward declaration allows factory:
MyVirt*CreateClass(){
return new SubVirt;
}
```

Update: Some of the comments say that forward declare is not enough to achieve the above, but that's not correct. You can accomplish the above fine without the full definition of the `SubVirt` class.

Now, what I want to do is have a custom constructor that takes arguments. As such:

```
MyVirt*CreateClass(){
return new SubVirt(arg 1, etc);
}
```

The problem is that a `class` forward declaration is no longer sufficient. It needs to see the class definition or its header. This means I can either move the factory method to the file where `SubVirt` is defined, or I have to include that file in the above file, which creates a circular dependency.

Is there a way to forward declare the custom constructor instead? That would make it all much simpler.

Comment: I have troubles understanding: `new SubVirt` also requires to see the definition of `SubVirt`, right? So the header must have been included

Comment: When return a pointer, compiler needs to know the concrete pointer size so forward declare is not enough.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: the `new` operator *needs* to see the class's definition, you can't just provide a forward declaration. It won't compile if an incomplete type is used. So it means you must have a header inclusion somewhere.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns And what kind of magic do you think `new` has for deducing the size of your object with just a forward declaration? Or should it take a potshot and hope the allocated memory is at least as big as your object? Your claims are nonsensical.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: I'm not sure what answer you refer to, but `new` needs to see the definition of the class in order to determine how much memory to allocate. How could it guess it from just the name of your class? Does your class contain 3, 4, or 145 member variables? Of what type? So either you are not showing us the real code, or you are not compiling any code at all.

Comment: @AndyProwl indeed it was eventually a compiler error but Xcode wasn't seeing the file at all, hence the cause of all this confusion, since it did indeed compile fine leading me to believe it was all working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CreateClass function looks odd, you miss `()` in function definition. Should be like this:

```
MyVirt* CreateClass()
{
    return new SubVirt(arg 1, etc);
}
```

When return a pointer, compiler needs to know the concrete type and constructor, so forward declare is not enough.

What you could do is:

- in header file: forward declare `SubVirt` and `CreateClass` function
- cpp file: include `MyVirt.h` and define `CreateClass` function

Comment: "When return a pointer, compiler needs to know the concrete pointer"
Pointer size is always the same. When you declare something that returns a pointer to structure, forward declaration is enough. When you _implement_ it, you need full declaration.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns that doesn't make sense

Comment: I'm not completely sure what we are discussing now. :D When you _declare_ Y, that knows about pointers/references to X, X can be forward declared before Y. When you _implement_ Y, and Y has to know about internal structure of X (like when you call "new X()"), it needs X's full declaration. That's really simple.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns that's not right, when new is called, it needs to know the type's constructor, forward declaration isn't enough.

Comment: [It doesn't compile, god damnit.](http://ideone.com/1liDGn) The `Derived` class isn't even derived from `Base`!

Answer (score 3):

Separate declaration from implementation, like everyone does.

MyVirt.h:

```
struct MyVirt{
...all virtual stuff
};
```

MyVirt.cpp:

```
#include "MyVirt.h"
Implementation of MyVirt
```

SubVirt.h:

```
#include "MyVirt.h"
struct SubVirt : MyVirt {
...all SubVirt stuff
};
```

SubVirt.cpp:

```
#include "SubVirt.h"
Implementation of SubVirt
```

Factory.h:

```
struct MyVirt;
MyVirt *CreateClass();
```

Factory.cpp:

```
#include "SubVirt.h"
MyVirt *CreateClass() { return new SubVirt() }
```

Comment: I liked your earlier version, where the `#include "SubVirt.h"` was in 76 pt bold font!  But you should really show a `#include "MyVirt.h"` in the SubVirt.h file.

Comment: I forgot about "code formatting" :P Yea, you're right, that header is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by separating the declaration and implementation.

The key here is to put the definition/implementation *above* the includes. Suppose you want to separate the classes A and B create two files like the following:

A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP

struct B; // fwd. decl.

struct A {
    int v;
    A(int v) {
        this->v = v;
    }
    B* createB();
};

#include "B.hpp"

A* B::createA() {
    return new A(v);
}

#endif A_HPP
```

B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

struct A; // fwd. decl.

struct B {
    int v;
    B(int v) {
        this->v = v;
    }
    A* createA();
};

#include "A.hpp"

B* A::createB() {
    return new B(v);
}

#endif // B_HPP
```

main.hpp

```
#include <A.hpp>
#include <B.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a(42);
    std::cout << a.createB()->createA()->v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You are of course free to move the implementation into a `cpp` file instead. This is only the basic recipe which shows how circular dependencies can be solved even for templated classes and functions.

http://codepad.org/IsBzQANX